# How can I find the most recent tag across all branches in a git repo?

Tags: git

I'd like to know how can I find the most recent tag across all branches in a git repo.

I've tried using the following command, but this only appears to check on the current branch:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 --tags | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'
```

I'd like to check all branches however.

Comment: Define "most recent". Do you mean the one that time-wise was created last? Or the one that is closest, topo-wise, to the tip of some branch?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script in bash.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#list all the tags 
git for-each-ref --shell refs/tags |
  awk '{
#transform the object name into the commit date as a Unix epoch timestamp 
    "git log -1 --pretty=%cd --date=unix "$1 | getline $1;
#if the tag does not refer to a commit, ignore it
    if($0 ~ /^[0-9a-f]/) print;
#sort by the timestamp reversely, from the youngest to the oldest
  }' | sort -r |
#get the first youngest tag
  head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' |
#get all the tags that point at this tag in case there are multiple youngest tags, 
#with a side effect to remove "refs/tags/"
  xargs -i git tag --points-at {}
```

One-line version:

```
git for-each-ref --shell refs/tags | awk '{"git log -1 --pretty=%cd --date=unix "$1 | getline $1;if($0 ~ /^[0-9a-f]/) print;}' | sort -r |head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -i git tag --points-at {}
```

If you are using Git before v2.9.4, use `--date=iso` instead of `--date=unix`. With `--date=iso` there might be a bug that the timestamps can't be sorted as expected due to time zones. But I think it's rare to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script in PowerShell to find the most recent tag. (Note that this doesn't check whether the tag is associated with a branch.)

```
# Out of all the tags, sorted oldest-to-newest...
git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname)' refs/tags `
    # Strip off the "refs/tags/" part of the name...
    | split-path -Leaf `
    # Take just the newest one.
    | Select-Object -Last 1
```